# Execute code when RabbitMQ server is unreachable

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-amqp` package to run `RabbitMQ` in `Spring Boot 2`. I have implemented an API in a remote server using which the listeners fetch the `RabbitMQ` config details and then connect to the `RabbitMQ` server. I am looking for a way such that if somehow the `RabbitMQ` server is unreachable for the listeners, the listeners should automatically send request to the server to get the new `RabbitMQ` config details. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify? If the server is unreachable, how are you going to get new configuration from the server?

Comment: RabbitMQ server is different from Rabbit config provider server.

Comment: RabbitMQ has high-availability configuration options... I would start there. What issue are you trying to solve/mitigate?

Comment: The user credentials and the license to access the RabbitMQ can change anytime, therefore I'm trying to make sure, that even when they change the listener can fetch the new credentials and access the RabbitMQ server. That's my use case.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're going to have to write code for that.

Comment: Currently I'm running a loop to check Rabbit health in every 5 seconds using `RabbitHealthIndicator`. I wonder if there's a better way than this ie. is there a construct where I can pass a function that will automatically be called when Rabbit connection is down?